# PostgreSQL Tables for team with unique player-combinations

Tags: sql, postgresql

In PostgreSQL, I have built these tables:

- Table `player` in which each player has a unique number `p_id`
- Table `team` that uses `t_id` as the primary key.
- Table `player_team` that records which players belong to which teams.

A sample of `player_team` is shown below. Team 001 has 3 members (200,300,400), Team 002 has 2 members (200,888), Team 003 has 3 members (999, 666, 333).

```
  player_team
  t_id | p_id | 
 ------+------+    
   001 | 200  | 
   001 | 300  | 
   001 | 400  | 
   002 | 200  | 
   002 | 888  | 
   003 | 999  | 
   003 | 666  | 
   003 | 333  |
```

In my scenario, there will be a large number of players and they are allowed to form to as many teams as they would like. The only constraint is that each member combination can only occur once. So a team formed by `(200, 300, 400)` will always have the t_id of `001`. This is required so I can track the performance of the same set of members over time, and how frequently certain members interact with each other.

How can this constraint be implemented in SQL? My incoming data will be tables in which each row is a player with a column `team name` which indicates which team they belong to when they played together. I cannot simply use `team name` as the same combination of players are free to choice a different name each time they play.

I am relatively new to this language so any directions are appreciated.

Comment: How do you define defined "time they play". Players form teams at random, but then do those teams has remain fixed for the short term, say 1 input table cycle (lets call that a match). Teams name are also random, but are they consistent over a match. Can a player be on multiple teams during a match, can the same combination of players appear with a different team name over a match. Your sample data has varying team size, what is the min and max team size. More to come I'm sure...

Comment: To achieve what you are after, I believe you would need to create an insert trigger, that checks if the record id about to be inserted into the player_team table would create a team that matches the membership of an existing team and if so, denies the insert. Unfortunately creating triggers is not normally a task you'd expect to do as a novice! Not that you need let that stop you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is too long for a comment.  Here are some alternatives.

First, you can use a trigger with your data as-is.  Just check that when new player are inserted into teams, then the combination does not exist.  Of course, this can be quite challenging.  If the trigger is checked for each inserted row, then a team of a single player might prevent that player from being the first player on any other team.  Ouch!

A second approach is to store a list of players on each team in the `teams` table.  This can be updated using a trigger on `player_team`.  And that list can have a unique constraint.  However, this has the same "ouch" as the first solution.

A third approach is to dispense with the `player_team` table and just store the team members as an array in `teams`.  The advantage of this approach is that *all* the players can be added as once.  That way, you don't need to worry about turning off or delaying constraint checks.

Of course, the third approach does not give you the same benefit of indexes.  However, you could store the list as a jsonb column, which allows indexes.

Comment: Apologies for the delayed credit. Thanks for the thoughtful solution--very helpful!